# Does ImagePicker API in iPhone OS 3.0 now include geo-tagging?

Tags: iphone

I'm looking at the ImagePicker API spec for iPhone OS 3.0 and don't see any reference to location being integrated into photo.  I know that with OS 2.x photos taken through ImagePicker would not include location data.  However I am wondering if anyone can confirm whether geo-tagging is indeed lacking in the new ImagePicker API as well.  Not sure why they would continue to leave this out when the native camera app has had it for awhile.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIImagePickerController still doesn't have any geotagged data that it attaches to the image unfortunately.  I agree that, by now, it is strange that it is still omitted.